# Office 365: Restricting Azure App to set of user

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, office365

We have created an Azure App which is installed by our clients. We have many users assigned Global Admins. The problem is each Global Admin user can see this Azure App. They need Global Admin because of some other reason but all of them do not need to manage that App. I worry about if that Azure App is accidentally modified by any one of those Global Admins and thereby affecting all clients.

I was looking way to restrict the App to set of users by **User assignment required** settings but have not found any working solution so far.

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-restrict-your-app-to-a-set-of-users

Basically, I set **User assignment required?** to Yes for that App and then assign only the required Global Amdin in the **Users and Group** but other Global Admin can still view and edit that App.

Answer (score 0):

A Global Admin by definition is the highest role you can give to a user in Azure Active Directory.
If you do not trust a user with that role, then they should not have that role.
You cannot restrict their access as they have the highest level of access available.
You can see the list of available directory roles and their permissions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/permissions-reference.

Note this quote in the docs (emphasis mine):

> Users who are assigned to the Global administrator role can read and
> modify every administrative setting in your Azure AD organization. By
> default, when a user signs up for a Microsoft cloud service, an Azure
> AD tenant is created and the user is made a member of the Global
> Administrators role. When you add a subscription to an existing
> tenant, you aren't assigned to the Global Administrator role. Only
> Global administrators and Privileged Role administrators can delegate
> administrator roles. **To reduce the risk to your business, we recommend
> that you assign this role to the fewest possible people in your
> organization.**
>
> As a best practice, we recommend that you assign this role to fewer
> than five people in your organization. If you have more than five
> admins assigned to the Global Administrator role in your organization,
> here are some ways to reduce its use.

You can also create custom directory roles now (in preview): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/custom-overview.
Those can be assigned on a much finer granularity and might help you as well.
A custom role can be assigned on a per-application level instead of directory level.